# Oracle database error 907: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Tags: sql, oracle, tableau-api

I transferred this code directly from SQL developer. Works perfectly in there.

```
SELECT 
    a.INCIDENT_NUMBER,
    a.DETAILED_DESCRIPTION,    
    a.INCIDENT_ROOT_CAUSE

FROM 
    N_EVALUATION as a

INNER JOIN N_DISPOSITION as b
    ON (a.INCIDENT_NUMBER = b.INCIDENT_NUMBER) 

WHERE
    b.DISPOSITION_LINE_NUM in (NULL, 1) AND
    a.ACTIVE_FLAG = 'Y' AND
    b.ACTIVE_FLAG = 'Y' AND
    a.DETAILED_DESCRIPTION IS NOT NULL
```

However when I transfer the same exact code into Tableau to create a custom SQL query. It gives me an error;

> An error occurred while communicating with the data source.  Bad
>   Connection: Tableau could not connect to the data source. Oracle
>   database error 907: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

This has me completely stumped, not really sure what to do here. Any help or advice is much appreciated. I am more concerned regarding the missing right parenthesis rather than the bad connection.

Comment: The query that you have posted has no unbalanced parentheses.  See details below, but the code does not work "perfectly" based on what I infer the intent to be.

Comment: Remove as keyword in from clause

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `AS` from the `FROM` clause.  Oracle does not recognize that.

In addition, this condition:

```
 b.DISPOSITION_LINE_NUM in (NULL, 1)
```

Does not do what you expect.  It never evaluates to true if `b.DISPOSITION_LINE_NUM` is `NULL`.

You should replace it with:

```
 (b.DISPOSITION_LINE_NUM IS NULL OR b.DISPOSITION_LINE_NUM = 1)
```

Otherwise, your query looks like it has balanced parentheses, but you should write it as:

```
SELECT e.INCIDENT_NUMBER, e.DETAILED_DESCRIPTION, e.INCIDENT_ROOT_CAUSE
FROM N_EVALUATION e JOIN
     N_DISPOSITION d
     ON e.INCIDENT_NUMBER = d.INCIDENT_NUMBER
WHERE (d.DISPOSITION_LINE_NUM IS NULL OR d.DISPOSITION_LINE_NUM = 1) AND
      e.ACTIVE_FLAG = 'Y' AND
      d.ACTIVE_FLAG = 'Y' AND
      e.DETAILED_DESCRIPTION IS NOT NULL;
```

Notes:

- User meaningful table aliases rather than arbitrary letters (this uses abbreviations).
- Do not use `as` in the `FROM` clause.
- Be careful with `NULL` comparisons.

Finally, your original query is equivalent to:

```
SELECT e.INCIDENT_NUMBER, e.DETAILED_DESCRIPTION, e.INCIDENT_ROOT_CAUSE
FROM N_EVALUATION e JOIN
     N_DISPOSITION d
     ON e.INCIDENT_NUMBER = d.INCIDENT_NUMBER
WHERE d.DISPOSITION_LINE_NUM = 1 AND
      e.ACTIVE_FLAG = 'Y' AND
      d.ACTIVE_FLAG = 'Y' AND
      e.DETAILED_DESCRIPTION IS NOT NULL;
```

**This has no parentheses.**  So it *cannot* return that particular error.

Comment: Now that is very fast!! Even less than 1 minute. Salute to you @gordon!!

Comment: Hello Gordon, thank you for your reply. I have modified my query however unfortunately still getting the same error code.

Comment: Thank you again @GordonLinoff, however the error still persists. Tricky issue this one.

Comment: @ARJ . . . I modified the answer.  The problem is the `as` in the `FROM` clause.  I don't know why this would have worked in any Oracle query.

Comment: Thank you @GordonLinoff, appreciate all that you have done. Unfortunately even with the modified code, the error persists.

Comment: My apologies, @GordonLinoff it worked! I believe i had copied and pasted it incorrectly. However can i ask why you decided to use "JOIN" instead of "INNER JOIN"?

Comment: @ARJ . . . It is easier to type and exactly equivalent.  I understand that folks who are newer to SQL prefer to be explicit.